# CUDA: __restrict__ tag usage

Tags: pointers, memory, memory-management, cuda

I don't quite understand the concept of the `__restrict__` tag in CUDA.

I've read that using `__restrict__` avoids pointers aliasing and in particular, if the variable pointed at is read-only, the reading of the variable is optimized because it's cached.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
__constant__ float M[M_DIM1][M_DIM2];

__host__ void function(float N[][DIM2], float h_M[][M_DIM2], float P[][DIM2]);

__global__ void kernel_function(const float* __restrict__ N, float *P);

__host__ void function(float N[][DIM2], float h_M[][M_DIM2], float P[][DIM2]) {

    int IOSize = DIM1 * DIM2 * sizeof(float);
    int ConstSize = M_DIM1* M_DIM2* sizeof(float);
    float* dN, *dP;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dN, IOSize);
    cudaMemcpy(dN, N, IOSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M, h_M, ConstSize);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dP, IOSize);

    dim3 dimBlock(DIM1, DIM2);
    dim3 dimGrid(1, 1);

    kernel_function << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> >(dN, dP);

    cudaMemcpy(P, dP, IOSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dN);
    cudaFree(dP);

}
```

Am I using the `__restrict__` tag on N, that is read-only, in the right way?
Furthermore, I've read that the keyword `__constant__` on M means that is read-only and constant, so what is the difference between the two of them, the type of allocation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`__restrict__` as used by `nvcc` is documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#restrict). (note that various c++ compilers including gnu compilers also have support for this exact keyword, and use it similarly).

It has essentially the same semantics as the C99 `restrict` keyword, which is [an official part of that language standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict).

In a nutshell, `__restrict__` is a contract that you as a programmer make with the compiler, which says, **roughly**, "I will only use this pointer to refer to the underlying data".  One of the key things that this takes off the table from the compiler's perspective is pointer aliasing, which can prevent the compiler from being able to make various optimizations.

If you'd like a longer formal treatise on the exact definition of `restrict` or `__restrict__`, please refer to one of the links I've already given, or do some research.

So, `__restrict__` is generally useful to compilers that support it, for optimization purposes.

For compute capability 3.5 or higher devices, these devices have a separate cache called the [read only cache](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0) which is independent of normal L1 type caching.

If you use both `__restrict__` and `const` to decorate global pointers passed to a kernel, then this is also a strong hint to the compiler, when generating code for cc3.5 and higher devices, to cause those global memory loads to flow through the read-only cache.  This can provide application performance benefits, often with little other code refactoring.  This doesn't *guarantee* usage of the read-only cache, and the compiler will often attempt to aggressively use the read only cache if it can satisfy the necessary conditions, even if you don't use these decorators.

`__constant__` refers to a **different** [hardware resource on the GPU](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constant).  There are many differences:

- `__constant__` is available on all GPUs, the read-only cache only on cc3.5 and higher
- memory allocated using the `__constant__` tag (which is included on the line to designate the allocation of memory) is limited to a maximum of 64KB.  The read-only cache has no such limit.  We don't put `__restrict__` on a line that allocates memory; it is used to decorate a pointer.
- data cached in the read-only cache has the typical global memory access considerations - normally we want adjacent and contiguous access for best coalescing of global memory reads through the read-only cache.  The `__constant__` mechanism, OTOH, expects so-called *uniform* access for fastest performance.  Uniform access essentially means that every thread in a warp is requesting data from *the same location/address/index*.

Both `__constant__` memory, and global memory marked with `const` decorator on the pointer passed to kernel code, are read-only from the perspective of kernel code.

I don't see any obvious problems in the code you have shown, whether with use of `__restrict__` or anything else.  The only comment I would have is that for maximal benefit you may want to decorate both the `N` and `P` pointers in your kernel declaration/prototype with `__restrict__`, for maximal benefit, if that is your intent.  (You would not decorate `P` with `const`, obviously.)

Comment: is `__restrict__` applicable to references like it is to raw pointers?

Comment: In the example from the [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#restrict), is there any difference between `void foo(const float* __restrict__ a,
         const float* __restrict__ b,
         float* __restrict__ c)` and `void foo(const float* __restrict__ a,
         const float* __restrict__ b,
         float* c)`? Does the latter make any sense?

Comment: It's not specified what the compiler behavior will be.  I suggest using `__restrict__` if applicable, on **all pointers** because this takes aliasing completely off the table.  This is also covered in the programming guide: *"Note that all pointer arguments need to be made restricted for the compiler optimizer to derive any benefit."* This is really getting into a precise description of `__restrict__` semantics which I didn't intend to get into in this question. You may wish to ask a new question.  I'm unlikely to respond to extended discussion in the comments on a 3 year old question.